# Does @material-ui/core have Typescript typings?

Tags: npm, material-ui, typescript-typings

Previous Material UI version 0.x had npm typings for Typescript. It was

`"@types/material-ui": "0.21.5"`

but it seems like there are no typings available for `"@material-ui/core": "3.0.1"`.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are bundled with the package. Just install `"@material-ui/core": "3.0.1"` and you have the typings.